# why the copy of strings does not work well Strcpy and Strtok

Tags: c

FTP server, I have to receive the response from the client to the command he send, but I have to split the response in two string. First the command and then the parameter.
when I want to do, the first token works, I mean, I manage to make operation equal to `"RETR"` but when I do the second token, I manage to make param equal to `"file.txt"` but now operation is left as `"RETRfile.txt "`

```c
    bool recv_cmd(int sd, char *operation, char *param) {

    char buffer[BUFSIZE], *token, *t;
    char *buffer_aux;
    int recv_s;

    memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    
    // receive the command in the buffer and check for errors
    recv(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    printf("buffer= %s", buffer);


    // expunge the terminator characters from the buffer
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;

    // complex parsing of the buffer
    // extract command receive in operation if not set \0
    // extract parameters of the operation in param if it needed
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");
  
    if (token == NULL || strlen(token) < 4) {
        warn("not valid ftp command");
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        if (operation[0] == '\0') {
        strcpy(operation, token);
        }

        if (strcmp(operation, token)) {
            warn("abnormal client flow: did not send %s command", operation);
            return false;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         if (token != NULL) 
         strcpy(param, token);
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Separate the logic in your program. Put the parsing logic in a separate function, and then create a [mre] using that function. We are missing half of the logic and information here, so it will be hard for other people to troubleshoot or reproduce.

Comment: If you don't check the number of bytes received by `recv()`, how do you know you have anything to print or tokenize?  Further, `recv()` reads binary data, it has no concept of a null-terminated C-string. Failing to pass a properly terminated string to `printf()` or any of the `str...()` functions invokes undefined behavior. You need to do character-oriented output and handling. Also, since `buffer` has automatic storage duration, `memset()` isn't needed, simply initialize `buffer` all zero, e.g. `char buffer[BUFSIZE] = {0};` or simply `char buffer[BUFSIZE] = "";`.